# Upgrading to xcode 3.2.3 issues

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have several iPhone apps and just upgraded to xcode 3.2.3 and have a few issues.

- Before, I used to simply select base SDK then do the build.  Now, I see where I set the Architecture Base SDK in my target but it's not 'base' it's Simulator of Device.  I also set the deployment target to 3.1.3 and now when I simply do a build so I can submit to Apple, it asks me to code-sign twice and doubles the files it is compiling.
- Code Signing Identity - I used to see a list of all my certificates and could see that xcode was correctly selecting the right one.  Now I simply see Distribution and Developer in the drop down...where are the list of app certs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the build settings to iPhone Device 4.0 (or 3.2 if you are targeting the iPad).  Setting the deployment target to the earlier version you want to support is the right thing to do.

If it's compiling twice, perhaps you are building a universal app?

In the drop down you should see the full list of certificates.  Check to make sure your provisioning profiles are all still in place, or try re-downloading one or two to see if they show up.

Comment: What do you mean by universal app?

Also, when go to window>organizer>provisioning profiles I see all my profiles, just don't see them in the drop down when I select the target>info>build>code signing identity.  I even drug it over again but it doesn't show up.